# How to use ng-show and ng-hide with buttons in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two buttons Start and Stop,when I click the Start button I want the Stop button to show and the Start button to be hidden vice versa when I click the Stop button I want the Start button to be shown and the Stop button to be hidden.Only one button must be shown at any one time.Here is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work.Where am I going wrong?

```
<span ng-hide="Model.StartEvent == true">
    <button ng-click="Model.StartEvent()" id="btnEventStart">Start</button>
</span>

<span ng-show="Model.StopEvent == false">
    <button ng-click="Model.StopEvent()" id="btnStopEvent" class="tooltip">Stop</button>
</span>
```

Comment: Use a single equals sign (confusing, I know). `Model.StartEvent == true` should be `Model.StartEvent = true`,e tc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use same variable for both...

```
<button ng-click="Model.toggleShow(); Model.StartEvent()" ng-show="Model.showStartEvent">Start</button>

<button ng-click="Model.toggleShow(); Model.StopEvent()" ng-show="!Model.showStartEvent">Stop</button>


Modal.toggleShow = function(){
  Model.showStartEvent = !Model.showStartEvent;
}
```

also you can call toggle right inside the startevent/stopevent rather than having two function calls on ng-click

Comment: I would use ng-hide="Model.showStartEvent" in the second button-looks more readable that way. Also I consider firing off multiple scope methods in ng-click a bad practice. Toggle of the propery should be done in existing start and stop methods.

Comment: @Capaj: i also agree on the `firing off multiple scope methods in ng-click a bad practice` and that why i intentionally put the comment `you can call toggle right inside the startevent/stopevent`

Answer (score 4):

You could do even less

```
<button ng-click="goEvent();" ng-hide="going">Start</button>
<button ng-click="goEvent();" ng-show="going">Stop</button>

...

$scope.going = false;

$scope.goEvent = function(){
   $scope.going = !$scope.going;
   if($scope.going){  
       $scope.go();
   }else{
       $scope.stop();
   }      
}
```

Comment: It could work but I need to have two different names for the ng-click event e.g Model.StartEvent() and Model.StopEvent()

Answer (score 0):

**Html:**

```
<div ng-controller="YourController">  
<span ng-hide="EventRunning"><button ng-click="StartEvent($event)"id="btnEventStart">Start</button></span> 
<span ng-show="EventRunning"><button ng-click="StopEvent($event)" id="btnStopEvent">Stop</button></span>  
</div>
```

Use single semaphore for hide and show *EventRunning*

**Controller:**

```
{ ...
     $scope.EventRunning = false;
     $scope.StartEvent = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $scope.EventRunning = true;
            // your code 
    }

    $scope.StopEvent = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $scope.EventRunning = false;
            // your code 
    } 
... }
```