# AngularJS I still see the two objects for 1ms while using ng-show ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have similar case of:
[How to use ng-show and ng-hide with buttons in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074688/how-to-use-ng-show-and-ng-hide-with-buttons-in-angularjs)

Where I have a play/pause buttons.
The ng-show/hide works, the only problem I have is that I still see the two objects for a 1ms

I've placed them one after the other like so:

```
<span ng-show="status() != 1">
   <span class="fa fa-play" ng-click="play()"></span>
</span>
<span ng-hide="status() != 1">
   <span class="fa fa-pause" ng-click="pause()"></span>
</span>
```

There's another object before & after those two buttons ( prev/next ) and when I click fast on play/pause - sometimes I don't see the two objects while switching them show/hide ( switch is fast ) but sometimes I do see see the pause/play button for a 1ms and then one of them disappears.

It's really bothering me, can someone suggest a different way of writing this ?

Comment: Have you tried [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)?

Comment: what is 'status' function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having flickering problems of DOM elements, then try to minimize what changes happen to the DOM. You can achieve the same results using just 1 span and make smaller changes to it.

```
<span class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-pause':status() == 1,'fa-play':status() != 1}" ng-click="status() == 1 ? pause() : play()"></span>
```

Changes in the DOM often originate from a parent scope, and propagate down the tree to all children. So in your example the first `<span>` is digested followed by the next sibling. So for a brief time one `<span>` is digested while the next sibling is still waiting to be digested.

You can make your HTML and JS code simpler by just using CSS to control visibility.

CSS

```
.playing .fa-play { display: none; }
.playing .fa-pause { display: inline; }
.stopped .fa-play { display: inline; }
.stopped .fa-pause { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<span ng-class="{playing:state()==1,stopped:state()!=1}">
      <span class="fa fa-play" ng-click="play()"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-pause" ng-click="pause()"></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use ng-show for both buttons but switch the condition for one of them to status() == 1

otherwise you could replace the two buttons with one and switch the css class and the click handler based on which "mode" it is in

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work, then I saw another example with ng-show/hide, and this is the example I used here, but both didn't work, thanks !